# How to link rand() to a while loop condition?

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple coin flip game and i'm not sure how to get it to print out a result if that makes sense. basically I'm not sure what to make the while condition to see if the answer is true or false. here is what i have so far. any help would be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
char answer;
int bank = 10;
int guess;
int h = 0;
int t = 1;

cout << "Welcome to the coin flip game. It cost a dollar to play." << endl;
cout << "If you guess correctly you will will $2.00" << endl;
cout << "Do you want to play <y/n>" << endl;
cin >> answer;
int flip = rand() % 3;
guess = flip;
while (toupper(answer) == 'Y')
{
    cout << "Your bank is $" << bank << endl;
    cout << "Enter heads or tails <h/t>" << endl;
    cin >> guess;

    while (guess == h)
    {
        bank++;
        cout << "Winner, the flip came up " << flip << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to play again <y/n>?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

its suppose to look like this [image: example of finished product]
and these are the guidelines [image]

Comment: With `rand() % 3`, the possible coin flip results are 0, 1, or 2. Does your imaginary coin really have three sides?

Comment: You need to decide if 0 or 1 is going to be head/tails. Then work from there.

Comment: Off the top of one's head, your message indicates entering heads or tails <h/t>, but cin is populating an int.  while (guess == h) doesn't want to be a while loop since nothing in there modifies guess or h.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh you're right no its suppose to be just two haha, I didn't think of that. so use to getting either 1 or 2. fixing that now.

Comment: @ArtYerkes how would I correct it? would I change cin to a char?

Comment: @AnthonyDrury well heads is 0 and tails is 1 but im not sure how to link my while loop with the rand

Comment: Take out a piece of paper. Write down in simple, logical sentences, what you want your program to do. Such as "read cin into a string variable. Compare it to X, if so set Y to Z, otherwise set N to M..." and so on. Once you've written down your logic, [discuss it with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck agrees that your proposed logic is sound, it should be directly translatable into C++ code.

Comment: I am confused, just place the rand inside the while loop? Make sure you seed the rand though.

Make the statement while guess != result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a look around the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section on [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You must put the `rand` call inside the loop (if you want to flip the coin more than once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    char answer;
    int bank=10;
    char guess;
    char result;
    cout << "Welcome to the coin flip game. It cost a dollar to play." << endl;
    cout << "If you guess correctly you will will $2.00" << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to play <y/n>" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    while (toupper(answer) == 'Y')
    {
        bank--;
        cout << "Your bank is $" << bank << endl;
        cout << "Enter heads or tails (h/t)" << endl;
        cin >> guess;
        if(rand()%2==1)
            result='t';
        else
            result='h';
        if(guess==result)
        {
            bank+=2;
            cout << "Winner, the flip came up ";
        }
        else
            cout << "Sorry, you lose. The coin flip came up ";
        if(result=='t')
            cout << "Tails" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Heads" << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to play again (y/n)?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    }

    cout << "Thanks for playing, your bank is $" << bank << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: hmm thanks this helped. didn't  get me exactly where I need to go but just enough to get me over the stump and thinking on how to get my problem fixed. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Since you put C++ as languange, I would strongly recommend you to review modern (C++11) random engines.

[Here is a good sample](http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/roll-a-die.html)